# Ubuntu 18.04 not upgrading to 18.10

Tags: update-manager

I am using Unity pack.
When I click on Upgrade to 18.10, nothing happens. I tried using Ubuntu also (rebooting and selecting Ubuntu option in settings), but no progress.

Please suggest

Comment: Did you try `apt update`, `apt upgrade`and `apt dist-upgrade` from a terminal?

Comment: here's a guide to upgrade from 18.04 to 19.04 : https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/upgrade-ubuntu-18-04-to-ubuntu-19-04-directly-from-command-line here's a guide from 18.04 to 18.10 : https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/upgrade-ubuntu-18-04-to-ubuntu-18-10 but I don't know why you'd want that specifically. just go to 19.04.

Answer (score 0):

First, open and edit `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` file and set `Prompt=normal` to avoid No new release found message. Save the file.
And then launch the command:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

If upgrading before the official 18.10 release date or while the upgrade from 18.04 is still not available use `-d` to perform upgrade:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

Comment: The `do-release-upgrade` command does not require sudo. It will prompt for your password anyway.